# Calling dynamic generated JSON in PHP file

Tags: php, json

I have dynamically generated json, from a MySQL database, based upon the url, for example `bookings/show/"1004"`

The reference can be changed, the problem I'm having is trying to get this data into a PHP file, I need to be able to call `bookings/show/`  with any reference and so it dynamically fills in the data. I don't know if I'm missing a trick. I also cannot use `get_file_contents()`

From my makepdf file I want to be able to go to `makepdf.php?invoice=1004`and it get all the data from the json file `bookings/show/1004`. I know I can't simple do `get_file_contents('bookings/show/1004')` because that is an invalid location

Comment: Try helping out to answer by spotting the actual problem, show some snippet code of your PHP and any error message that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do from the following process.

```
$result=getdata("https://api.example.com?id=1&name=example&limit=2")
$data = json_decode($result,true);
echo '<p>Name : '.$data['result']['name'].'</p>
      <img src="'.$data['id']['id'].'"><br>';
```

Comment: I can't use full urls, has to be a local, plus what is inside the function getdata()?